# gradle publish jars with different classifiers, dependency missing

Tags: gradle, maven-publish

Gradle new maven-publish plugin:

For multiple jars with different classifiers, e.g.,

source sets

```
src/foo/java
src/bar/java

dependencies {
    fooCompile group: 'org.slf4j', name: 'slf4j-api', version: '1.7.25'
    barCompile sourceSets.foo.output
}
```

Jars to build:

```
productName-1.0-foo.jar
productName-1.0-bar.jar
```

bar.jar has compile dependency on foo jar.

Gradle:

```
publishing {
    publications {
        mavenJava(MavenPublication) {
            groupId 'com.example'
            artifactId 'productName'
            version '1.0'

            artifact fooJar {
                classifier 'foo'
            }

            artifact barJar {
                classifier 'bar'
            }
        }
    }

    publishing {
        repositories {
            maven {
                url "$buildDir/repo"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The published repository:

```
build/repo/com/example/productName/1.0/productName-1.0-foo.jar
build/repo/com/example/productName/1.0/productName-1.0-bar.jar
build/repo/com/example/productName/1.0/productName-1.0.pom
```

Only one pom without any dependency.

Now separate these with different artifactId (s)

```
publishing {
    publications {
        foo(MavenPublication) {
            groupId 'com.example'
            artifactId 'productName-foo'
            version '1.0'

            artifact fooJar {

            }
        }

        bar(MavenPublication) {
            groupId 'com.example'
            artifactId 'productName-bar'
            version '1.0'

            artifact barJar {

            }
        }
    }

    publishing {
        repositories {
            maven {
                url "$buildDir/repo"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Each jar gets its own POM:

```
build/repo/com/example/productName-foo/1.0/productName-foo-1.0.jar
build/repo/com/example/productName-foo/1.0/productName-foo-1.0.pom

build/repo/com/example/productName-bar/1.0/productName-bar-1.0.jar
build/repo/com/example/productName-bar/1.0/productName-bar-1.0.pom
```

Two issues:

1. the classifier (foo, bar) is not after version in jar name.
2. the generated POM.xml files for foo and bar do not have dependency.

Comment: Have you managed to solve this?

Comment: I believe I have experienced the same issue: https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/21038

Comment: @eastwater how did you resolve this?

Comment: do not have separate pom files for foo and bar. So dependencies inside pom file will not work.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative approach that works for me.  Something similar might work for you:

```
task sourcesJar(type: Jar, dependsOn: classes) {
    classifier = 'sources'  
    from sourceSets.main.allSource
}
// If needed the javadoc task can be commented, comment javadoc from artifacts and publish as well.
task javadocJar(type: Jar, dependsOn: javadoc){
    classifier = 'javadoc'
    from javadoc.destinationDir
}

task testJar(type: Jar, dependsOn: testClasses) {
    from sourceSets.test.output
    appendix 'test'
}

artifacts{
    archives sourcesJar
    archives javadocJar
    archives testJar
}

publishing {
    publications {
        mavenJava(MavenPublication) {
            from components.java
            artifact sourcesJar
            artifact javadocJar
        }
        mavenTest(MavenPublication) {
            artifactId project.name + "-test"
            artifact testJar {
                appendix 'test'
            }
        }
    }
}

artifactory {
    publish {
        defaults {
            publications ('mavenJava', 'mavenTest')
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This helps for publishing, but doesn't work when you want to link the test artifact within project without reading it from published maven repository.

Comment: You may be interested in testFixtures instead of manually building a 'testJar'. See https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_testing.html#sec:java_test_fixtures